# Android - How do you make a button invisible but still active?

Tags: java, android, button

I am trying to create a "hot spot" on my tablet that acts like a button but users can not see the button. When I try the following I have a button but when visibility is set to "4" the user cannot interact or see it:

```
  Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b);
      b.setOnClickListener(listener);
      b.setVisibility(4);

    public OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MeetingManager.this,GetRoom.class);
           startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    };
```

Any ideas how I can achieve the above request?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it is going to be invisible, why does it have to be a button?

You can add an **OnClickListener** to any view.

Why not use an *ImageView* with a transparent background and just add the **OnClickListener** to that?

Comment: Good idea. Just a question could it be applied to a layout element like a tableRow? +1

Comment: Yes, anything that extends the *View* class can implement an **OnClickListener**, including a tableRow.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can add a normal button and change its background to a transparent png picture it works fo me !